# SQL XML PATH creates special Chars and Message 402, level 16, State 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, htmlspecialchars

Good morning,

I have 2 problems with the following query I wrote, I hope you can help me with one of these and that it is ok to have two problems in one post.

**Query description:**
This Query combines features (feature name, feature value, Article ID) from an article into one row/column to insert it as an html table into the article description

**Problem 1:**
The html table tags inside the string are getting transformed into html specialchars

**Problem 2:**
In the Update statement

```
SET [eazybusiness].[dbo].[tartikel].cBeschreibung = [eazybusiness].[dbo].[tartikel].cBeschreibung + b.beschreibung
```

I am getting an error message.

I try add the table I created to the description column of the article

> Message 402, level 16, State 1, line 27
>   The data types text, and nvarchar(max) are incompatible in the add operator.

**Query:**

```
WITH firstquery as(
     Select distinct am1.kartikel, 
            Substring(
                (
                    Select m.[cName] + '</td><td>' + mw.[cWert] as 'td'
                    FROM  [mydb].[dbo].[tArtikelMerkmal] as am 
                        JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[tMerkmal] as m
                            ON am.kMerkmal = m.kMerkmal
                        JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[tMerkmalWertSprache] as mw
                            ON am.kMerkmalWert = mw.kMerkmalWert
                    WHERE am1.kMerkmal = am.kMerkmal and am1.kMerkmalWert = am.kMerkmalWert and am.kartikel = 69079
                    For XML PATH ('')
                ),1,10000) [Beschreibung]
        FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tArtikelMerkmal] as am1 Where am1.kartikel = 69079),
        secondquery as(
        Select distinct kartikel,'<table>' +
                Substring(
                    (
                        Select Beschreibung as 'tr'
                        FROM firstquery as b
                        Where a.kartikel = b.kartikel
                        for XML PATH ('')
                    ), 1 , 10000) + '</table>' [Beschreibung] 
        FROM firstquery as a)
        --Select * FROM secondquery
        Update [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel]
        SET [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel].cBeschreibung = [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel].cBeschreibung + b.beschreibung
        FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel] 
        INNER JOIN secondquery as b
        ON [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel].kArtikel = b.kArtikel
        Where [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel].kArtikel = 69079
```

**Result:**
In the Column 'Beschreibung' (description) you will see that some of the html tags are transformed into html special chars
the result query is from the 'Select * FROM secondquery'

```
kartikel    Beschreibung
69079   <table><tr>&lt;td&gt;ACPI-Version&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;5.0&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Anzahl DVI-D Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Anzahl Ethernet LAN (RJ-45) Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Anzahl HDMI Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Anzahl PS/2 Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Anzahl USB 2.0 Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;2&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Anzahl USB 2.0 Schnittstellen&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Anzahl USB 3.0 Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;4&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Anzahl VGA (D-Sub) Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Arbeitsspeicher Typ&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;DIMM&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Audio Kanäle&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;7.1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;BIOS-Speichergröße&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;8 MB&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;BIOS-Typ&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;UEFI AMI&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Breite&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;30,5 cm&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Clear CMOS-Jumper&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Ja&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;CPU Ventilatorstecker&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Ja&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Eingebauter Ethernet-Anschluss&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Ja&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Front Panel Audiostecker&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Ja&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;HDD Schnittstellen&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Serial ATA III&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Kompatible Prozessoren&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Celeron, Core i3, Core i5, Core i7, Pentium&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Komponente für&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;PC&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;LAN-Controller&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Intel I218V&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Mitgelieferte Kabel&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;SATA&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Motherboard Chipsatz Familie&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Intel&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Motherboard Chipsatz&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Intel Z97&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Motherboardformfaktor&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;ATX&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Ohne ECC&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Ja&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Parallele Verarbeitungstechnologie&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Quad-GPU CrossFireX&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;PCI-Express x1 (Gen 2.x)-Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;2&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;PCI-Express x16 (Gen 2.x)-Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;PCI-Express x16 (Gen 3.x)-Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;PCI-Slots&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;3&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Prozessorfamilie&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Intel&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Prozessorsockel&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Socket H3 (LGA 1150)&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;RAID Level&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;0, 1, 5, 10&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;S/PDIF aus Stecker&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Ja&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;SATA III Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;4&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Speicherkanäle&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;doppelt/Dual&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Speichersteckplätze&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;4&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Tiefe&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;21,8 cm&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;TPM-Verbinder&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Ja&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Unbuffered Speicher&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Ja&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Unterstützte Arbeitsspeicher&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;DDR3-SDRAM&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Unterstützte Arbeitsspeichergeschwindigkeit&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1333, 1600, 1866, 2000, 2133, 2200, 2250, 2400, 2600, 2666, 2800, 2933, 3000 MHz&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;unterstützte Windows Betriebssysteme&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;Windows 7 Home Basic, Windows 7 Home Premium, Windows 7 Professional, Windows 7 Starter, Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows 8, Windows 8 Enterprise, Windows 8 Pro, Windows 8.1, Windows 8.1 Enterprise, Windows 8.1 Pro&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;USB 3.0-Anschlüsse&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;3&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Zahl der Chassisventilatorstecker&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;3&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Zahl der COM Stecker&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td&gt;Zahl der EATX Energie Stecker&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;1&lt;/td&gt;</tr></table>
```

Comment: For your update statement cast your both columns to the same datatype . And for first query cast it to the `xml` so the tags will be selected as it is

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem to html are getting converted to the special characters you can use [Explicit mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx).

```
 WITH firstquery as(
 Select distinct am1.kartikel, 
        Substring(
            (
                Select  1 as tag,
                 null as parent,
                  m.[cName] + '</td><td>' + mw.[cWert] as 'td'
                FROM  [mydb].[dbo].[tArtikelMerkmal] as am 
                    JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[tMerkmal] as m
                        ON am.kMerkmal = m.kMerkmal
                    JOIN [mydb].[dbo].[tMerkmalWertSprache] as mw
                        ON am.kMerkmalWert = mw.kMerkmalWert
                WHERE am1.kMerkmal = am.kMerkmal and am1.kMerkmalWert = am.kMerkmalWert and am.kartikel = 69079
                for xml explicit
            ),1,10000) [Beschreibung]
    FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tArtikelMerkmal] as am1 Where am1.kartikel = 69079),
    secondquery as(
    Select distinct kartikel,'<table>' +
            Substring(
                (
                    Select  1 as tag,
                    null as parent, Beschreibung as 'tr'
                    FROM firstquery as b
                    Where a.kartikel = b.kartikel
                    for xml explicit
                ), 1 , 10000) + '</table>' [Beschreibung] 
    FROM firstquery as a)
```

For your second problem you need to cast the text as the `varchar`

```
    Update [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel]
    SET [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel].cBeschreibung = Cast([mydb].[dbo].[tartikel].cBeschreibung AS nvarchar(max)) + b.beschreibung
    FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel] 
    INNER JOIN secondquery as b
    ON [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel].kArtikel = b.kArtikel
    Where [mydb].[dbo].[tartikel].kArtikel = 69079
```

Comment: Message 6801, level 16, State 1, line 1
FOR XML EXPLICIT at least three columns are required: the tag column, the parent column, and at least one data column.

Comment: Sorry copy paste mistake. Updated the query please check. Comment in case of issue.

Comment: I got errors, so I edited the tags of the explit, now the code is working again, but the second query still modifies all the tags from the first query into special chars